# How do I get the sum of the first two sequences when the user enters "2" as "n"?

Tags: java

The sequence is: `sum = 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + 1/25+...`

When I enter "2" it just gives me the sum of 1.25. How do you get it so when "2" is entered, it is adding 1 + 1/2?

Oh and I'm in an entry level java course so I we cant use arrays or anything that advance yet.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //declarations
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0;
        int n;

        //input
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        //process
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter += 1)
        {
            sum += 1.0 / (counter*counter);
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the general formula for the terms of your sequence?. It looks like 1/(i^2) except there's that pesky 1/2. Are you sure it belongs there?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your sequence, 1.25 is the correct answer.

Comment: My professor put it in there so i'm assuming he wants that in there.

Comment: Your "professor" has made a mistake. A sensible sequence would be `1/1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16 + 1/25`. You may get extra marks for being the first to point it out.

Comment: Maybe the misprint is that 9 should be 8 and 25 should be 32.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your problem, i have used Math.pow() to get the sequence running and not multiplying it twice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        //declarations
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //to generate this sequence we take the first two as constants and start generating from the third onwards
        double first = 1;//first number in the sequence
        double second = 0.5;//second number in the sequence
        double sum = first+second;//adding first and second
        int n;

        //input
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if(n==1){
           System.out.println("The sum is: " + first);
           return;
        }
        if(n==2){
           System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
           return;
        }
        //process
        for(int counter = 2; counter <n; counter += 1)
        {
            sum += 1.0 / Math.pow(counter, 2);//will be computed when you enter values when n is more than 3

        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
     }
```

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with OP's code. The problem is with the task definition.

Comment: You do NOT need to use `Math.pow`.  And if the only power you'll be raising things is 2, it's far better to do it by multiplying.

Comment: If I enter "1" as "n", I get 1.5; which it is supposed to 1. Otherwise this is sooo close to getting it!

Comment: @KoulaeMoua fixed the code, it will work for all cases now

Comment: @Bohemian I feel with his code he can never generate first two numbers of the sequence, try it yourself.. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @DavidWallace can you please tell me why multiplying two is better?

Comment: Multiplying two integers is better than calling `Math.pow()` because it is **much** faster.

Comment: It's not MUCH faster, but it's a little faster than a floating-point multiplication.  `Math.pow` is implemented in the JVM.  The implementation does a number of preliminary checks, to deal with common and easy-to-calculate cases.  One of those checks is to check whether the exponent is 2, and if so, to get the result by performing a floating-point multiplication.  These checks don't take terribly long, BUT, it's always going to be better just to save the JVM from having to do these checks, and code the floating-point multiplication directly.  Of course, as @TedHopp correctly points out, ...

Comment: when you're dealing with integers, the multiplication is considerably faster.  Integer operations at processor level will always be faster than the corresponding floating point operations.

Comment: As far as the downvote is concerned ... I downvoted your answer for two reasons.  (1) It is false - you claim that OP _needs_ to use `Math.pow()`.  This, of course, is nonsense.  (2) It is not useful.  It will not solve OP's problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks, I will change it now

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks for the elaborated explanation... learnt something new today

Comment: @DavidWallace - The comparison should be between one `int` multiply and subsequent promotion of `int` to `double` vs. the following: 1) promotion of `int` to `double`; 2) overhead of calling a two-argument `static` method; 3) check for special case; 4) `double` (not `float`) multiplication. I stand by my statement that the `int` multiply is MUCH faster. According to [this study](http://dhruba.name/2012/09/01/performance-pattern-multiplication-is-20x-faster-than-math-pow/), `double` (not `int`!) multiply can be up to **20x faster** than calling `Math.pow()`.

Comment: @TedHopp That study's results aren't really applicable here.  It deals with the general case, where the exponent is any positive integer.  The Hotspot JVMs have some special logic for the case where the exponent is exactly 2.  Intuitively, the `Math.pow` implementation looks like `if (exponent == 2.0) { return base * base; } else { do clever stuff }`.  If you compare the performance of `Math.pow(x,2)` with `x*x`, you'll find the difference is actually very small.  However, that's no excuse to use the former.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Yes, the study I cited may not be the most relevant. However, we're still talking here about a 32-bit `int` multiply vs. a 64-bit `double` multiply (not `Math.pow(x,2)` vs. `x*x`). The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) say that floating point is about half the speed of integer operations on modern Android platforms. Other literature suggests that multiply could be even slower in other environments. And if this code happens to be running on a platform without an FPU, it's game over.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that 1/2 must be part of the sequence, so be it. (But that's a bizarre sequence and I strongly suggest that you double check this with your professor.) I'll assume that the remainder of the sequence is defined by 1/i<sup>2</sup>. Note that with these assumptions, the sequence terminates at 1/(n-1)<sup>2</sup> rather than 1/n<sup>2</sup>.

You'll need special handling for the cases `n == 1` and `n > 1`. One possibility is to initialize `sum` to 1 if `n == 1`; initialize it to 1.5 if `n > 1`; and otherwise initialize it to 0. Then start the loop at `counter = 2` and change the loop termination condition to `counter < n` (instead of `<=`).

Answer (score 0):

If that's your sequence then you should really start by setting the sum equal to `1.5` and then rest of it will work. Your sequence should be a geometric sequence `1/n^2` I think it's a mistake.

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 1.5;
        int n;

        //input
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        if(n==1)
          System.out.println("The sum is: " + 1);
        //process
        for(int counter = 2; counter <n; counter++) {
            double mul = counter*counter;
            sum += 1.0/mul ;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

}
```

Output :

```
    Enter n: 
    2
    The sum is: 1.5
    Enter n: 
    3
    The sum is: 1.75
```

Comment: But when the user enters "1" they get 0.0.

Comment: You can simply add the condition for that. Add that as a special case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage "1" and "2" as special cases.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sum
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    //declarations

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0;
        int n;

        //input
        System.out.println("Enter n: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        //process
        for(int counter = 1; counter <= n; counter += 1)
        {
          if (counter == 1)
            sum = 1;
          else if (counter == 2 )
            sum += 1.0/((counter-1)+(counter-1));
          else 
            sum += 1.0 / ((counter-1)*(counter-1)); 
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just do `sum += 1.0` when `counter == 2`

Comment: @criket_007 When counter == 2 you need to add 1/2 to sum. I know I can just write `sum += 0.5;` but I want to show the relation with counter and why is different to the other cases.

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't see the plus in there.

Answer (score -2):

As per your for loop, the sequence generated will be `1 + 1/(2*2) + 1/(3*3)+ ......`

So, when you enter `2` => `1+1/(2*2) = 1+0.25=1.25`.

Otherwise, your logic is Good. you can implement few exceptions, but as you mentioned that you re new to Java, you ll slowly encounter them.

Happy Learning Java  :)

Comment: The question asked how to get 1.5, though. It should be clarified in the comments above if the sequence should contain `1/2` as a value

Comment: Please read the question once againWhen I enter "2" it just gives me the sum of 1.25. How do you get it so when "2" is entered, it is adding 1 + 1/2?

Comment: Right. And your "answer" doesn't address OP's question at all. It merely explains the current (undesired) behavior.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for your suggestion, but I need it so that when the user enters "2" when prompted, it should print out 1.5. When "3" is entered it should be 1.75.